# System.Entity.DbSet<TEntity> working mechanism in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbset

I was wondering how `DbSet` actually sets itself.

If you see the definition of `DbSet`, it is a concrete class.

But all the methods are not implemented making it looks more like `interface`.

```
public class DbSet<TEntity> : DbQuery<TEntity>,
                              IDbSet<TEntity>, 
                              IQueryable<TEntity>, 
                              IEnumerable<TEntity>, 
                              IQueryable, 
                              IEnumerable, 
                              IInternalSetAdapter where TEntity : class

...

 public virtual TEntity Add(TEntity entity);
```

I see that `DbSet` class has a base class and many interfaces. but none of them actually implements the methods like `Add` and It doesn't have members that holds the `DbContext`

I was wondering what's going on.

So on this subject, initial questions will be..

- Where does the `DbSet` methods get implemented?
- No in-memory storage(?) for `DbSet`?

Thank you for everyone for your insights.

Comment: use a decompiler like dotPeek to take a look at the implementation of the classes.

Comment: @Jehof: there is no need to use decompiler, EF is open source.

Comment: my question looks diff somehow. open source EF and dotPeek I will try those. thanks you